# unable to show button on first load with ngIF

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to show a button when I edit a input form. I hide the button when the page loads and it will show when I edit any of the input fields. I have highlighted the input box whenever I edited it. Whenever I edited my input field I would get error
"NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'"

the button would still not appear. however when I click on a random location of the browser, my button would appear. may I know what is the issue here ?

ts

```
button: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void{
this.button = false;
}

highlight(input: string): string{
    //color...
    if (input.dirty) {
      //color
      this.button= true;
    }
    return color;
  }
```

html

```
<button *ngIf="button" label='Submit'>
```

Comment: When is `highlight` called?

Comment: highlight is a ngclass

Comment: I see you have accepted another solution now, but it would have made it easier for us to help you if you included the code where highlight is used. Just a tip for next time you ask a question, include anything that can be relevant :)

Comment: @ShamPooSham: Things eventually became more clear when JJJJJJ created a stackblitz-example (it is linked in the comments below my answer). So the best idea would probably be to include a stackblitz-example from the beginning ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to tackle your issue with a complete different approach, which is also included in my own **[stackblitz-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-mtkc3h?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fhello.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.css,app%2Fapp.module.ts)**:

- you want to show a button whenever at least one form-field has some input
- you want to highlight every input-field that has some input

The **CSS File**

Define a custom styling for input-fields that have an input. Thereby we use a trick with css. We create an empty placeholder for the number-field and whenever the placeholder is hidden, it means that the field has an input :-):

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  border: 3px dashed yellow;
}
```

The **TS File**

We subscribe to changes in the form. Whenever a change in the form happens we check whether at least one field contains a value and therefore the button has to be displayed. The incoming `res`-object actually contains all properties of your form together with their values.

```
myform: FormGroup;
showButton = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myform = new FormGroup({
    numbers: new FormControl(null),
    otherNumbers: new FormControl(null),
  });

  // Subscribe to changes in your form and set the button visible,
  // if at least one form-field is not empty:

  this.myform.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
    let showBtn = false;
    for (const property in res) {
      showBtn = !!res[property] ? true : showBtn;
    }
    this.showButton = showBtn;
  });
}
```

The **HTML File**

Don't forget to add a placeholder with an empty space, otherwise the above mentioned trick with the styling wouldn't work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1">
      <form [formGroup]="myform">
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            pInputText
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="numbers"
            placeholder=" "
          />
        </td>
        <br />
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            pInputText
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="otherNumbers"
            placeholder=" "
          />
        </td>
      </form>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="showButton" label="Submit">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried calling detectchanges() and i received the error maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I modified my solution by changing the if-statement to `if (input.dirty && this.button == false)`. Can you try again?

Comment: Btw: You error implies that you were caught in an endless loop, but I hope my code-modification will interrupt this loop ;-).

Comment: i tried the newly updated solution but now the error is still the same error above but its value is my color. where my highlight would be missing

Comment: Maybe you could create a stackblitz-example because based on your currently provided code it's really hard to tell how to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-qvza4x?file=app/app.component.ts this is the stackblitz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251236/discussion-between-jjjjjj-and-kellermat).

Comment: I updated my answer, because I think you should choose a completely different approach.