# how to hide/show div with primeng checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, toggle, primeng

Simple question.
I am trying to hide/show `div` in angular depending on the checkbox condition.

Currently, I am using primeng checkbox but my code does not work.. can anyone please advise me?

Here is the code I made:

**<home.component.html>**

```js
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="showMe" [binary]="true"></p-checkbox>

<div *ngIf="showMe"> example </div>
```

**<home.component.ts>**

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  showMe: boolean = false;

}
```

Should I consider using `(onChange)` in this case?

Comment: Basically your code seems correct. Yet if you have set the Change-detection-strategy to `onPush`, it might not work.

Comment: I made a stackblitz-example of your code and it works perfectly (as long as I'm using the default change-detection strategy): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-j7de2v?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Sorry but forgot to mention this is under formControl... the code is complaining i cannot define [(ngModel)] and form at the same time.. instead, I need to use formControlName. I should dig into the primeng doc more.

Comment: It has nothing to do with primeNG. You should indeed not use [(ngModel)] in a reactive form. Instead you could subscribe to the form an react to changes in the form. I answered a very similar question just a couple of hours ago. This question was about showing/ hiding a button based on changes in a reactive form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157390/unable-to-show-button-on-first-load-with-ngif/75157455#75157455

Comment: I solved it with the below reference. Thank you anyways! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022981/check-box-selection-to-enable-disable-textboxes-using-angular-reactive-forms